# NotFoundHttpException after deploying laravel project with api.php, why?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-5

I have uploaded the laravel project in root in a folder called wajabatapp, and the content of the public folder I moved them to public_html folder, and I've edited the index.php to refer to the folder named wajabatapp.

When I entered the url if gives NotFoundHttpException page, I've double checked the routes and everything is fine.

[image]

Note: I use laravel 5.4 and PHP version 5.6

Is there any other configuration I miss?

Comment: routes/web.php please

Comment: I use api.php not web.php

Comment: api routes have /api/ in the url by default, unless you change the provider behaviour. What is the exact call you are doing?

Comment: site.com/api/info
when I call it gives me a new exception "MethodNotAllowedHttpException"

Comment: Paste the content of routes/api.php

Comment: use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
Route::post('/user/register_email', 'User\userController@registerWithEmail');   // Params: name, email, password

Comment: @AbdalltifBasher you said you're calling site.com/api/info, but I don't see that route defined in your api.php

Comment: There are lots of routes that I didn't write cuz the limited number of characters in comments

Comment: @AbdalltifBasher edit your post and add your api.php code to the question.